# sql stored procedure - multiple users create temp table at the same time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Suppose a temp table would be created and dropped during a stored procedure. What if multiple users run the stored procedure at the same time, does it cause any problem like unable to create that temp table because it's been already created by another user and hasn't been dropped yet in time before someone tries to create that temp table?

Comment: @JasonA.Long you should put that into an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: @RussellFox - Moved to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're talking about an actual #temp table (with a single #) there are no problems. A #temp table is scoped to the session. So you can have dozens of people on the same instance, all creating temp tables with the exact same name, at the exact same time and you'll never have a collision. (It's a different story if you're talking about ##globaltemp tables (with 2 ##)... Global temps can and do collide with other sessions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I'm talking about single # temp table.